# Better tag editor UX in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app, user-interface

In the Android app, entering tags is a bit cumbersome, especially on a high-latency connection. You need to type a substring of the tag name, then wait for the server to return the list of matches, then select the tag in the list.

Please allow typing the full name without waiting for feedback from the server. In that case the tags should be validated in a single batch when leaving the tag editor. Yes, delayed validation is inferior UX, but it's still better than very slow validation at every step. It's also confusing, at least when you're used to the website, that you can type `foo bar` in the tag edit box and hit “Submit”, but that will not result in tags `foo` and `bar`.

Also, when displaying completions, please display the exact match first if there is one. Currently it can be difficult to locate when it's a substring of more popular tags.